# How to run an R script file on powerpoint (VBA)

Tags: r, powerpoint

### I have this script file:

```
library(fBasics) # Load the package fBasics.
da=read.table("C:\\Users\\jose\\Tese\\Analysis of Financial Time Series\\dibm3dx7008.txt",header=T) # Load the data.

dim(da) # Find size of the data: 9845 rows and 5 columns.
da[1,] # See the first row of the data

ibm=da[,2] # Obtain IBM simple returns
sibm=ibm*100 # Percentage simple returns
basicStats(sibm) # Compute the summary statistics
```

---

And I want to run it from powerpoint;
I have tried the VBA in powerpoint, can anyone help me

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I use both Powerpoint and R and trying to call R from PPoint sounds like an unnecessarily difficult approach. Would it not be easier to extract the data as shown above, then export the results either in CSV form for formatting in Excel, or plot them in a chart that you can then save or copy for manual insertion into Powerpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you might take a look at using Sweave (or knitr) with beamer slides.

Answer (score 1):

You could put your Script into a  *.bat file and then execute this from Powerpoint via Shellexecute. But this is a terrible pain and highly vulnerable to changing filelocations.

Some code:

```
Dim wshshell As Object
Set wshshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 'a shellconsole
Dim Shellscript as String
ShellScript = "c:\yourscript.bat" 'if this contains white spaces you have to add chr(34)  at the beginning and end of the string.

wshshell.CurrentDirectory = YourProgramPath 'set the current directory
wshshell.Run shellscript, , True 'run the script

'then parse the results -sorry I have no idea how to do this in R.
```